# Calculating total by using amount and discount via js?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some textboxes. My Html code is:

```
<input type="text" id="amt_5" onkeyup="calculateTotal(5);" style="width:50px" name="data[Fee][fee_to]">
<input type="text" id="dis_5" onkeyup="calculateTotal(5);" style="width:50px" name="data[Fee][fee_to]">
<input type="text" id="total_5" style="width:50px" name="data[Fee][fee_to]">

<input type="text" id="amt_6" onkeyup="calculateTotal(6);" style="width:50px" name="data[Fee][fee_to]">
<input type="text" id="dis_6" onkeyup="calculateTotal(6);" style="width:50px" name="data[Fee][fee_to]">
<input type="text" id="total_6" style="width:50px" name="data[Fee][fee_to]">



Total Fees Amount
<span id="Fees_amt" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>
```

and my js code is:

```
<script>
   function calculateTotal(pid){

       //alert($id_particular);
      var amt=document.getElementById('amt_'+pid).value;
      var dis=document.getElementById('dis_'+pid).value;
      if(amt != "" && dis != ""){
      var total = (amt-((dis*amt)/100));
      }
      else if(amt != "" && dis == ""){
      var total = amt;
      }
     else{
     var total = "";
     }
     document.getElementById('total_'+pid).value=total;
     }
</script>
```

Above code basically works as:
Takes the amount value from `textbox(amt_5,amt_6)`, takes the discount value from `textbox(dis_5,dis_6)`, calculate the total and fills in the `textbox(total_5,total_6)` by js

Now what i want to do is:
Whatever the total comes in `total_6` or `total_5`, adds them and fills in my span element with id `Fees_amt`

This should be done via js, enhancing my js code and without refreshing the page.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your existing JavaScript code, you could add something like:

```
document.getElementById("Fees_amt").appendChild(document.createTextNode('' + total));
```

On another note, your current code isn't fantastic in the sense that every time someone types a character in a single input field, the entire calculation function is run. While the code works, I would advocate adding a button for the user to click once the values have been entered into the input field. While requiring more user input I think this is a cleaner way of organizing your code.

**edit based on further clarification**
If you want the sum of `total_6` and `total_5` the easiest way (while maintaining your current JavaScript structure would be to maintain the values in two global JavaScript variables. This would then look something like this:

```
<script>
   var total5 = 0,
       total6 = 0;

   function calculateTotal(pid){
      var amt=document.getElementById('amt_'+pid).value;
      var dis=document.getElementById('dis_'+pid).value;
      if(amt != "" && dis != ""){
        var total = (amt-((dis*amt)/100));
      }
      else if(amt != "" && dis == ""){
        var total = amt;
      }
     else{
       var total = "";
     }
     document.getElementById('total_'+pid).value=total;
     if(pid==5){
         total5 = total;
     } else{
         total6 = total
     }
     document.getElementById("Fees_amt").appendChild(document.createTextNode(total6 + total5));
  }
```

While this should work I would strongly recommend you rethink the way you are handling this problem.

Comment: Your answer is concatenating the total, not adding it

Comment: Just to clarify, what exactly do you want to add? The values in `total_6` AND `total_5` ?

Comment: Well, you have set the value of either `total_6` or `total_5` to `total` using your provided code. So, if you set the value of the span to `total` this will automatically be the same.